# View email/newsletter in browser?

Tags: email, email-templates, newsletter

I'm configurating email templates and can't find how to add a link to view the current email in browser, in case it don't show up correctly in the Client.

Have been google for few hours now and can't to find any info on the subject.

Does this feature exists in Magento? If yes, how to add an correct URL in the template?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not exist out of the box in Magento. You can use an integration like MailChimp or CampaignMonitor to have this feature without coding it yourself.
See [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-extension.html) and [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fontis-campaign-monitor.html) for some references.

Comment: That's sad. Do you know any other extension? We don't want to use Mailchimp or any other similar service. Thanks

Comment: There are free plans. I don't know any other extension for managing transactional emails. Remember to mark the question as accepted if it helped you.